# to find code for eigenvalue

Tags: java

I want java code for finding eigenvalue from square matrix.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: How about googling a bit: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+matrix+eigenvalue

Comment: we are not code factory.

Comment: I've never seen so many requests for eigenvalues.  They must all be in the same class.

Answer (score 3):

If you need it for a school project, study the [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm), write the code and learn. You can find numerous examples on google (search for "java eigenvalue").

If you need it for production use (e.g. a scientific project for large-scale computing), use [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/).